# Change value in array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

I want Year 2015,January to show 24 and February to show 25.  Next year 2016 January starts at 36.

[image]

This is my code

```
<?php 
     for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; $i++) {          
         $years[$y]  = $y = date("Y", strtotime("+$i years"));
         $months[$m] = $m = date("F", strtotime("Jan +$i months"));
        foreach ($years as $year => $value[$m]){                 
             $array[$year] = $value; 

         }
     } 
     echo '<pre>'; 
     print_r($array);
     echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Can you reword your question. It might just be me, but I can't work out what you're actually trying to do or where you're getting stuck.

Comment: Also, `"++$i years"` isn't going to work the way you think it will.

Comment: Can you see picture in my question ? Maybe you will understand ?

Comment: Yes we can see the image, but there's no context for what it's showing up. Is that what it's giving you, is that what you're wanting? What?

Comment: I just edit picture i wanna my result like picture. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I fixed your English in the post and I have attached the image.  In future it would be better if you just typed it in.  You are expecting other people to put the effort in to help you.  Surely, you can put some effort in to make it easier for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So going from the comments, I can't really work out how you came to the code you've provided. To be honest, I would recommend looking through some PHP documentation and tutorials before continuing as you seem to be missing some knowledge of basics such as arrays and loops.

That being said, again going by your comments, the following should produce what you're after:

```
<?php
$iterator = 24;
$array = array();

foreach(range(2015, 2016) as $year) {
    foreach(range(1, 12) as $month) {
        $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $month);
        $monthName = $dateObj->format('F');
        $array[$year][$monthName] = $iterator++;
    }
}


echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

This should be easily editable to your needs.